# UnauthorizedAccessException on FAT32 when running as Admin?

Tags: c#, windows, exception, permissions, io

I wrote my own C# script to delete folders (it must falls under certain conditions). It worked well until today on a specific folder. I get a UnauthorizedAccessException error when trying to delete a folder.

The folder is on a FAT32 external HD and i cant delete it. Theres no permissions, no files in it and it isnt read only. Yet i get the error. I can delete it via windows explorer but my tool cant. Even if i run it in admin mode. Why is this happening?

-edit- ok the first time i guess it was a file that gave me that exception. ATM its a folder which gets me IOException. the msg is "Access to the path '...' is denied." .

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this with the same folder and attempt multiple times?  If so, how are you doing that?  Making a copy of the folder and attempting to delete the copy?

Comment: @mellamokb actually the first folder i was stupid and did shift+del. This folder has the same qualities (no files in it) so i inspected it and it looks like my app should be able to delete it (especially with admin priv). I run it more than once and it reports an exception each time. -edit- after copy/paste the folder i see the app can delete the copy.

Comment: Are there any processes having any sort of lock on the folder, i.e., with tool like WhoLockMe/Unlocker/ProcessExplorer?  Where did these folders originate from - were they created by another application, or are they like a mirror copy of somebody's internal HD?

Comment: They are all mine. I forgot how i made them as some of these are >1yr old. No process is in them. I can delete them in windows explorer w/o problems. Its just my app that cant do it. I wish there was an error code i can look up. The msg is access violation. I'm started debugging it once again

Comment: I know you said the folder is not read-only, but can you try this anyway? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/142991/Unauthorized-Access-Exception-when-trying-to-dele.  Also, regarding your update, can you post the exact path you are trying to delete and a screenshot of the folder in Windows Explorer (make sure you have show both hidden and system files enabled in Folder Options).

Comment: @mellamokb ok next time i will and i'll ping you. I kind of got fed up 20mins ago and just deleted it and continue on. I'll check next time this happens

Comment: Ya the other simple thing would be to catch the exception and just log to a log file somewhere, so you can review later.  That way your script can continue, and you can handle the exceptions on an as-needed basis manually.

Comment: Thats actually how i found the problem ;) @mellamokb